# How do I click the "Add to Cart" button inside of a form tag with selenium chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button, css-selectors

I'm trying to code a program that will order pizza for me with automation. In the process, I ran into an issue, and it is that I cannot seem to find the "Add to Cart" button and click it with driver.find_element_by_css_selector() or xpath. I think it may have to do something with the fact that the button is inside of a form tag.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from time import sleep
chromedriver = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://www.papajohns.com/")
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.page-wrapper > header > section.nav-utility > nav > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a")
button.click()
driver.get("https://www.papajohns.com/order/stores-near-me")
address = driver.find_element_by_id("locations-streetaddress")
address.send_keys("address")
zipCode = driver.find_element_by_id("locations-usa-zipcode")
zipCode.send_keys("zip")
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#locations-form > div.button-set > input")
submit.click()
driver.get("https://www.papajohns.com/order/menu")
sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("shopCartProduct")
```

Link to website:
https://www.papajohns.com/order/menu

How can I access the "Add to Cart" button?

P.S. The button should be the first button tag that appears in the html code.

Comment: include the code you've tried so far and any exceptions you receive.  Also avoid posting screenshots of the markup. (and expand the node there...)

Comment: can you share the link of website of something similar